# button names are blurred after disabling in Internet Explorer

Tags: asp.net

my asp buttons are getting blurred after disabling them through code in Internet Explorer.on mozilla it is working fine.
Css applied to buttons are

```
.Login-btn{
    font-family: Tahoma;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    background-image: url('../images/Login-btn.jpg');
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    padding-right: 20px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    display: block;
    width: auto;
    float: left;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin-left: 10px;
    }
```

Login-btn.jpg is blank image on which i am writing text.what can be the problem

Comment: Do you have any images of this blurriness?

Answer (score 0):

Well, IE gives a disabled effect to html buttons ignoring whatever CSS that you may have. So there are no real solutions but few work-arounds:

1. Instead of disabling button, add a onclick handler that would return false (but button will still remain click-able).
2. Create your own custom button implementations that rely on hyper-links

Answer (score 0):

You should create a separate style selector for disabled buttons, something like this should work across most browsers, even IE (7+):

`.Login-btn[disabled="disabled"], .Login-btn.disabled{
}`

see: [this link](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/attributeselector#compatibilitysection)